# Why are my apps loading very slowly?

Tags: applications

Lately, I've been having with my phone when I try to open some apps. Usually games, they spend a long time sitting on the opening splash screen before eventually starting up properly. This can take up to ten minutes, with no visible progress. Once the game is running, it's perfectly fine. Doesn't run sluggishly or have long waiting/loading times.

My phone is a Moto G4 running Android 7.0. unrooted and with no modifications. This has come up with Animal Crossing Pocket Camp, Monument Valley 2 and Space Team. I tried moving the apps to internal storage, but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Does anyone have any idea of what might be causing this?

Comment: The fact it only happens with games suggests it might be a GLES problem, e.g. with shader compilation or texture upload, but I can't imagine how you might break that on a particular phone. Is your phone rooted, or have you done any other system modifications?

Comment: @DanHulme Nope, my phone isn't rooted and doesn't have any modifications to the system. I added this detail to my question.